# Compute logistic regression on tweet objects

Tags: python, exception-handling, statistics, machine-learning

Is my approach good to naming variables and exception handling? I would like to make this code more robust and maintainable.  I need advice on exception handling, var naming and comments.

```
    import config_files
    import math
    """
    Performs logistic regression on tweets object passed and returns followback prediction
    """

    class LogisticRegression():
        """
        method: Constructor
        input: 
                Object: Config file object

        output: None

        """  
        def __init__(self,config):
            self.config =config
        """
        method: Computes and returns sigmoid function of sent parameter
        input: 
                Integer: Prediction Paramter

        output:
                Float: Sigmoid function value on the parameter

        """

        def sigmoid(self,x):
            return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

        """
        method: Performs generalised linear regression (glm) on the tweet object
        input: 
                Integer List: glm variables  
        output:
                Float: Prediction (between 0-1)

        """

        def glm(self, variables):

            logistic_regression_predictors  = [self.config.logistic_regression_parameters[0],0,0,0,0,0]

            logistic_regression_vars = self.config.logistic_regression_parameters

            key_pos_bin = variables[0] 
            user_power_bin = variables[1]
            tweets_count = variables[2]
            user_favorites_count = variables[3]
            user_tweet_length = variables[4]

            if key_pos_bin == True:
                logistic_regression_predictors[1] = logistic_regression_vars[1]

            if user_favorites_count == 3:
                logistic_regression_predictors[2] = logistic_regression_vars[2]

            elif user_favorites_count == 2:
                logistic_regression_predictors[2] = logistic_regression_vars[3]

            elif user_favorites_count == 0:
                logistic_regression_predictors[2] = logistic_regression_vars[4]

            if tweets_count == 2:
                logistic_regression_predictors[3] = logistic_regression_vars[5]

            if user_power_bin == False:
                logistic_regression_predictors[4] == logistic_regression_vars[6]

            if user_tweet_length == False:
                logistic_regression_predictors[5] == logistic_regression_vars[7]

            x = logistic_regression_predictors[0] + logistic_regression_predictors[1] + logistic_regression_predictors[2] + logistic_regression_predictors[3] + logistic_regression_predictors[4] + logistic_regression_predictors[5]

            return self.sigmoid(x)

        """
        method: This method computes and sends all the variables for the glm method
        input: 
                Object: Tweet object in json format
                String: Keyword of tweet
        output:
                Float: Prediction (between 0-1)

        """
        def userFollowBackPrediction(self,tweet,keyword):

            keyword = keyword.lower()

            key_pos_bin = 0
            user_power_bin = 0
            tweets_count = 0
            user_favorites_count = 0
            user_tweet_length = 0


            try:
                if tweet['text'].lower().index(keyword) < self.config.tweet_keyword_index:
                    key_pos_bin = False
                else:
                    key_pos_bin = True
            except:
                key_pos_bin = False

            try:


                user_power = tweet['user']['friends_count']/tweet['user']['followers_count']

                if user_power >= self.config.user_power:
                    user_power_bin = True
                else:
                    user_power_bin = False

            except Exception as ex:
                user_power_bin = 0

        #calculate tweets_count

            user_status_count = tweet['user']['statuses_count']

            if  user_status_count <=self.config.user_status_count:
                tweets_count = 1
            else:
                tweets_count = 2


        ##calculate user_favorites_count
            user_favorites_count = tweet['user']['favourites_count']

            if  user_favorites_count == self.config.user_favorites_count[0]:
                user_favorites_count = 0
            elif user_favorites_count >self.config.user_favorites_count[0] and user_favorites_count <=self.config.user_favorites_count[1]:
                user_favorites_count = 1
            elif user_favorites_count >self.config.user_favorites_count[1] and user_favorites_count <=self.config.user_favorites_count[2]:
                user_favorites_count = 2
            elif user_favorites_count >self.config.user_favorites_count[2]:
                user_favorites_count = 3

        #calculate user_tweet_length

            if keyword in tweet['text'].lower() :
                user_tweet_lengthext = len(tweet['text'])-self.config.tweet_link_length-len(keyword)          
            else:
                user_tweet_lengthext = len(tweet['text'])-self.config.tweet_link_length

            if user_tweet_lengthext < self.config.tweet_content_length:
                user_tweet_length = False
            else:
                user_tweet_length = True

            user_followback_prediction = self.glm([key_pos_bin, user_power_bin, tweets_count, user_favorites_count, user_tweet_length])

            return user_followback_prediction
```

Comment: Your docstrings need to be below the `def` to be attached to the object properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start : your naming convention does not follow [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which is the usually accepted style guide for python code.

---

`sigmoid()` does not need to operate on an instance.

---

In Python, you can chain your comparison in a clean way. For instance :

```
        if  user_favorites_count == self.config.user_favorites_count[0]:
            user_favorites_count = 0
        elif user_favorites_count >self.config.user_favorites_count[0] and user_favorites_count <=self.config.user_favorites_count[1]:
            user_favorites_count = 1
        elif user_favorites_count >self.config.user_favorites_count[1] and user_favorites_count <=self.config.user_favorites_count[2]:
            user_favorites_count = 2
        elif user_favorites_count >self.config.user_favorites_count[2]:
            user_favorites_count = 3
```

can be written :

```
    if  user_favorites_count == self.config.user_favorites_count[0]:
        user_favorites_count = 0
    elif self.config.user_favorites_count[0] < user_favorites_count <= self.config.user_favorites_count[1]:
        user_favorites_count = 1
    elif self.config.user_favorites_count[1] < user_favorites_count <= self.config.user_favorites_count[2]:
        user_favorites_count = 2
    elif self.config.user_favorites_count[2] < user_favorites_count:
        user_favorites_count = 3
```

---

You can use list unpacking to rewrite :

```
        key_pos_bin = variables[0] 
        user_power_bin = variables[1]
        tweets_count = variables[2]
        user_favorites_count = variables[3]
        user_tweet_length = variables[4]
```

just in one line :

```
        key_pos_bin, user_power_bin, tweets_count, user_favorites_count, user_tweet_length = variables
```

This is probably not required at all as variables could be just as easily passed one by one.

---

You don't need to assign to a temporary variable `user_followback_prediction` before returning.

---

From the PEP 8 linked above :

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==.

---

Using an array for `logistic_regression_predictors` adds some un-needed complexity.

---

You should try to understand which errors can be thrown instead of having `try` `catch` all over the place.

---

The documentation is a nice touch but does not help at all as it's just a rewritten form of the signature of the function : a description of the structure of the config or such a thing could be helpful.

Also, I have doubts that the way things have been splitted is really relevant : 
`logistic_regression_predictors` seems to be getting the right pieces of information to feed `glm` but them `glm` itself will perform some non-trivial logic before calling `sigmoid`. I guess this could be a single function and be just as clear (which doesn't mean much).

This is probably as far as I can go without understanding much of it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import config_files
import math

"""
Performs logistic regression on tweets object passed and returns followback prediction
"""
class LogisticRegression():
    """
    method: Constructor
    input:
            Object: Config file object
    output: None
    """
    def __init__(self,config):
        self.config =config

    """
    method: Computes and returns sigmoid function of sent parameter
    input:
            Integer: Prediction Paramter
    output:
            Float: Sigmoid function value on the parameter
    """
    def sigmoid(x):
        return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

    """
    method: Performs generalised linear regression (glm) on the tweet object
    input:
            Integer List: glm variables
    output:
            Float: Prediction (between 0-1)
    """

    def glm(self, key_pos_bin, user_power_bin, tweets_count, user_favorites_count, user_tweet_length):
        logistic_regression_vars = self.config.logistic_regression_parameters

        logistic_regression_predictors_0 = logistic_regression_vars[0] 
        logistic_regression_predictors_1 = logistic_regression_vars[1] if key_pos_bin else 0

        if user_favorites_count == 3:
            logistic_regression_predictors_2 = logistic_regression_vars[2]
        elif user_favorites_count == 2:
            logistic_regression_predictors_2 = logistic_regression_vars[3]
        elif user_favorites_count == 0:
            logistic_regression_predictors_2 = logistic_regression_vars[4]
        else
            logistic_regression_predictors_2 = 0

        logistic_regression_predictors_3 = logistic_regression_vars[5] if tweets_count == 2 else 0

        logistic_regression_predictors_4 == logistic_regression_vars[6] if not user_power_bin else 0

        logistic_regression_predictors_5 == logistic_regression_vars[7] if not user_tweet_length else 0

        return sigmoid(logistic_regression_predictors_0 + logistic_regression_predictors_1 + logistic_regression_predictors_2 + logistic_regression_predictors_3 + logistic_regression_predictors_4 + logistic_regression_predictors_5)

    """
    method: This method computes and sends all the variables for the glm method
    input:
            Object: Tweet object in json format
            String: Keyword of tweet
    output:
            Float: Prediction (between 0-1)

    """
    def user_follow_back_prediction(self,tweet,keyword):
        keyword = keyword.lower()

        try:
            key_pos_bin = tweet['text'].lower().index(keyword) >= self.config.tweet_keyword_index:
        except:
            key_pos_bin = False

        try:
            user_power_bin = tweet['user']['friends_count']/tweet['user']['followers_count'] >= self.config.user_power:
        except Exception as ex:
            user_power_bin = 0

        #calculate tweets_count
        tweets_count = 1 if tweet['user']['statuses_count'] <=self.config.user_status_count else 2


        ##calculate user_favorites_count
        user_favorites_count = tweet['user']['favourites_count']

        if  user_favorites_count == self.config.user_favorites_count[0]:
            user_favorites_count = 0
        elif self.config.user_favorites_count[0] < user_favorites_count <= self.config.user_favorites_count[1]:
            user_favorites_count = 1
        elif self.config.user_favorites_count[1] < user_favorites_count <= self.config.user_favorites_count[2]:
            user_favorites_count = 2
        elif self.config.user_favorites_count[2] < user_favorites_count:
            user_favorites_count = 3

        #calculate user_tweet_length

        if keyword in tweet['text'].lower() :
            user_tweet_lengthext = len(tweet['text'])-self.config.tweet_link_length-len(keyword)
        else:
            user_tweet_lengthext = len(tweet['text'])-self.config.tweet_link_length

        user_tweet_length = user_tweet_lengthext >= self.config.tweet_content_length:

        return self.glm(key_pos_bin, user_power_bin, tweets_count, user_favorites_count, user_tweet_length)
```

Comment: did you intend to leave the self out of sigmoid?